# Display die('message') problem

Tags: php, javascript

How do i display the die() message in if($allowed) at the same place as move_uploaded_file result?

```
<?php
  $destination_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/uploads/';

  $allowed[] = 'image/gif'; 
  $allowed[] = 'image/jpeg';
  $allowed[] = 'image/pjpeg'; 
  $allowed[] = 'image/png'; 

  if (!in_array($_FILES['myfile']['type'], $allowed)) { 
    die('Wrong file type!'); 
  } 

  $result = 0;

  $now = time();

  $ext = end(explode(".", $_FILES['myfile']["name"]));

  $filename = ( $_FILES['myfile'][0].$now.".".$ext);

  if(@move_uploaded_file($_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'], $destination_path .$filename)) {
     $result = 1;
  }

  sleep(1);
?>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> window.top.window.stopUpload('<? php echo $result; ?>', '<?php echo $filename; ?>');</script>
```

Javascript to display move_uploaded_file result:

```
 function stopUpload(success,filename){
  var result = '';
  if (success == 1){
     result = '<span class="msg">Great!<\/span><br/><br/>';
  }
  else {
     result = '<span class="emsg">Not so great.<\/span><br/><br/>';
  }
```

Comment: not your question, but this doesnt work `$ext = end(explode(".", $_FILES['myfile']["name"])); `  either split that into two lines or use pathinfo

Comment: Doesn't work? for what? The uploaded files gets named "timestamp.ext" eg 1294601292.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you mean in the same condition?

```
if (in_array($_FILES['myfile']['type'], $allowed) && @move_uploaded_file($_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'], $destination_path .$filename)) { 
  $result = 1;
} else {
  die("Error while uploding file");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a third `$result` condition (-1, for example), then instead of `die(message);`, do `$result = -1; exit(0);`. Change the JavaScript so `else if (success == -1) { result = 'Wrong file type!' }`